# Compruebo CheckBox y TextView juntos, pero no funciona correctamente

Tags: java, android

Sé que hay muchas preguntas sobre comprobar si `CheckBox` está seleccionado o si `TextView` está vacío, pero intento hacer una comprobación de ambos juntos y no la realiza, lo que he hecho es lo siguiente.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // compruebo si opc1 u opc2 está seleccionado y si openCalendario no está vacío
                if (opc1.isChecked() || opc2.isChecked() || verificarCampoFecha()) {
                    // solamente ir si opc1 u opc2 está seleccionado y openCalendario no está vacío
                    Intent c4c5a = new Intent(Clase4.this, Clase5.class);
                    startActivity(c4c5a);
              } else {
                    // opc1 opc2, si alguno de los dos no está seleccionado, mostrar:
                    Toast.makeText(Clase4.this, "Por favor, seleccione una franja horaria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // verificarCampoFecha, si openCalendario está vacío mostrar:
                if (openCalendario.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                     Toast.makeText(Clase4.this, "Por favor, seleccione un día", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
       }
   });

// compruebo openCalendario

  private boolean verificarCampoFecha() {
        if (openCalendario.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

El problema es que si `TextView` está vacío y `CheckBox` sin seleccionar, solamente muestra el `Toast` de `CheckBox` y si el `CheckBox` está seleccionado, pasa a la siguiente `Activity` sin tener en cuenta si `TextView` está vacío o no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenos días campañera @UserNameYo, según veo por el comentario que esta en el código requieres hacer:

```
 // compruebo si opc1 u opc2 está seleccionado y si openCalendario no está vacío
```

con este codigo estas preguntando esto:

```
// compruebo si opc1 u opc2 está seleccionado u openCalendario no está 
    if (opc1.isChecked() || opc2.isChecked() || verificarCampoFecha())
```

para realizar lo que esta puesto en el comentario combiene poner un "and" "&&" el codigo te quedaria algo asi:

```
if ((opc1.isChecked() || opc2.isChecked()) && (verificarCampoFecha()))
```

espero haberte ayudado.

Agregado a respuesta.

Referente al toast de la seccion de codigo.

```
// opc1 opc2, si alguno de los dos no está seleccionado, mostrar:
  Toast.makeText(Clase4.this, "Por favor, seleccione una franja horaria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

aquí tendríamos que meter el mensaje si se cumple esa condicion algo asi como:

```
if (!opc1.isChecked() && !opc2.isChecked()){
// opc1 opc2, si alguno de los dos no está seleccionado, mostrar:
  Toast.makeText(Clase4.this, "Por favor, seleccione una franja horaria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: me alegra que te haya servido en parte, eso ocurre si los 2 CheckBox están desmarcado y el TextView esta relleno ?

Comment: Ahh creo que entiendo, solo falta agregar la verificación antes de emitir el Toast, lo agrego a la respuesta para que se vea un poco mejor

Comment: ah ya si perdon puse or enves de and en la condiccion ahora lo edito

Comment: Perfecto! Ahora sí, gracias^^